# Meteor Publish / Subscribe Race Condition

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a file that's defining the publish / subscribe behavior but it only works maybe one in 10 times. When it doesn't work, the query comes back as undefined. I can do successful queries in chrome's console, so it must be loading after after the query fires.

[project root]/lib/site.js

```
Articles = new Mongo.Collection("articles");
Authors = new Mongo.Collection("authors");

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish("articles", function () {
        return Articles.find();
    });
    Meteor.publish("authors", function () {
        return Authors.find();
    });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe("articles");
    Meteor.subscribe("authors");
}
```

[project root]/client/modules/articleAdHelper.js

```
var getArticle = function (id) {
    var article = Articles.findOne({articleID: id});
    var author = Authors.findOne({_id: article.authorID});
    article.authorName = author.authorName;
    article.authorPageUrl = author.authorPageUrl;
    article.authorAvatar = author.authorAvatar;
    article.articlepublishTimePassedMessage = getPublishDateMessage(article.articlePublishDatetime);
    return article;
};

var getAdUnit = function (unitKey) {
    for (var i = 0; i < unitKey.length; i++) {
        unitKey[i] = getArticle(unitKey[i]);
    }
    return {
        m: [
            unitKey[0],
            unitKey[1]
        ],
        h: [
            unitKey[2],
            unitKey[3],
            unitKey[4],
            unitKey[5]
        ]
    }
};


var articleID = "testarticle";
var adUnitObj = getAdUnit([
    "testarticle",
    "claudeArticle",
    "emusk",
    "claudeArticle",
    "testarticle",
    "adCreatePageTest"
]);
Template.frontPageArticleAdUnit.helpers(adUnitObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that you are only calling `getAdUnit` once, which only works (as you found) if the subscription is ready at the time of the call. I'm unclear if you want a non-reactive solution, so I'll present two options:

**non-reactive**

If you want the ad unit data to be generated exactly once (so the ads don't change), then you'll need to wait on the subscription before rendering the page. If you are using iron-router, you'll need to add a `waitOn` hook to your route.

**reactive**

If the ad unit data can change, you'll need to return a **function** for your helpers rather than a single object resulting from a single call. That way the data will update as authors and articles become available to the client.

I'd recommend reading [this post](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards) on using guards in meteor.